# Apache Camle CXF Logging < as &lt and > as &gt

Tags: logging, soap, cxf, jbossfuse

I am using Apache CXF interceptor for logging like this

```
<cxf:inInterceptors>
  <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
</cxf:inInterceptors>
<cxf:outInterceptors>
  <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"  />
</cxf:outInterceptors>
```

But the LoggingOutInterceptor logging my exchange payload in &lt and &gt Format

like this

```
&lt;firstname&gt;Chittaranjan&lt;/firstname&gt;  
&lt;lastname&gt;Panda&lt;/lastname&gt;
```

But I want it in this format

```
<firstname>Chittaranjan</firstname>
<lastname>Panda</lastname>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your example XML is not in itself invalid, you're seeing 'inner xml', i.e. XML in XML as text or CDATA nodes.

It is basically not possible to just unescape the whole XML string because then there is a conflict between correctly and incorrectly encoded XML.

I've written a [library](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components) which lets you easily work around this, i.e. [go](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/blob/master/spring.cheat.sheet.md) with **prettyPrintCData** or **prettyPrintTextNodes**.